# Setting up an OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio

Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong in this code as my on clicklistener is not working and the numbers from 0 to 1 do not appear .

```
public class FunFactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);
    Button showFactButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showFactButton);

    button.setOnClickListener(
       new Button.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
             TextView factTextView =
                     (TextView)findViewById(R.id.factTextView);
             factTextView.setText("button clicked ");



           }
       }
    );

    //declare are View variables and assign the views from the layout file
    final TextView factLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextView);



    View.OnClickListener Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //the button was clicked, so update the fact label with a new fact
            String fact = "";
            // randomly select a fact
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();//construct a new random generator
            int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
```

Comment: still stuck i will upload load the code this is now confusing

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
View.OnClickListener Listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
```

that to

```
showFactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // DO STUFF
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Button showFactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showFactButton);
   showFactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

//Your Code
}});
```